# white space between title and plot in ioslides

Tags: r, markdown, ioslides

I am using the default theme of ioslides for a presentation, and I have difficulties with arranging a plot on the slide.

I use the following code for the respective slide:

````
```{r crint1, fig.width = 7, fig.height = 5.5, fig.retina = NULL, fig.align="center"}
options(warn=-1)
load("path_to_data.RData")
ord <- order(cor.table$COR)
barplot(cor.table$COR[ord], names.arg=cor.table$group[ord],horiz=T
        , cex.name=.6, border=F, space=.3, col="gray30", 
        xlab="Correlation Coefficient", las=1)
  grid(NULL, NA, col="white", lty="solid", lwd=0.7)
    abline(v=mean(cor.table$COR), lwd=2, lty=2, col="red")
      text(mean(cor.table$COR), 1, "Average", cex=.8, col="red", pos=4)```
````

Which results in this:

[image: link to image]

Which is okay, but I would like the plot to start right below the title and extend more on the slide, so the names of the rows are readable and don't overlap.

I tried to play around with `fig.height` and `fig.width`, but they only extend the size of the plot and do not change the starting coordinates (which makes the plot extend beyond the slide).

Is there any way to reduce the white space below the title and use that margin to extend the plot? I assume I have to edit the CSS for that particular slide, I am just not sure how. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try the following:

**Option 1:**

Give your slide an `id` (here it is `#slideID`) and change the margins:

```
## Slide_title {#slideID} 
<style> 
  #slideID > p { 
    margin-top: -50px; 
  } 
</style>
```

**Option 2:**

Identify the slide with the plot (in my case its `id` is `slide-1` and add the following styles:

```
<style>
    #slide-1 > p {
      margin-top: -50px;
    }
</style>
```

The plot is included with an `img` tag. And a paragraph `p` is wrapped around it. We want to move this one up by `50px`.
Additionally you can also alter the margin inside the plot to minimize the white space above the plotting area.

[image]

(For identifying the correct slide: open the presentation, display the slide with the plot and use the *inspect element* option inside of a browser (or the RStudio viewer) to view the source code)

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I just altered a bit your code, so one does not need inspect: `## Slide_title {#margins}
<style>
    #margins > p {
      margin-top: -50px;
    }
</style>` where `margins` is a tag set by the user in the slide's header.

Comment: @Endre Even better :)

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer Is there any way to do this globally for every slide?  Or more specifically for every slide thats not title or h1?  And does this code go in the Rmd or the css?